# Dealing with non-stationarity in panel data

Tags: panel-data, stationarity, dependent-variable

I am using panel data for my analysis. My dependent variable is non-stationary while all my explanatory variables are stationary. Also, my dependent variable is a bounded variable (an index variable having range between 0 and 1, which has been constructed by me).

I am not sure of whether I can take the log of a bounded variable (to make it stationary). Please give me some suggestion as to how I should deal with this non-stationarity problem in a dependent variable.

Answer (score -1):

I do not see the reason why you would avoid the log. In real world data is used for transformations, for example if you have bounded variables and you wish to make them free.

In general, try various known stationarity transformations (log, exp, diff, growth etc). Check their plots and use a standard statistical test to verify their stationarity (ADF for instance).

More importantly, you have to remember that practically you create a new variable from this. Therefore, whatever method you use it is advisable to know what the new, transformed, variable shows/means (interpretability).